# What import should I use for keyboard scanners and Math.?

Tags: java

I tried every import I know, and it still basically keeps giving me class, interface, or enum expected error on every line that uses Keyboard or Math.

If you're wondering what the program does, it's suppose to find the distance between 2 points that the user puts in.

```
// Sam
// 9.25.13
// import csl.Keyboard from the L: drive jdk
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class swagggg
    public static void main ( String [] args)
    {
        // declare variables
        int x1, y1 ,x2, y2;
        double distance;
        // get user input 
        Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the first set of coordinates: ");
        x1 = Keyboard.nextInt();
        y1 = Keyboard.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the second set of coordinates: ");
        x2 = Keyboard.nextInt();
        y2 = Keyboard.nextInt();
        // calculate using the Math class static method
        distance = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2-x1,2) + (Math.pow(y2-y1,2));
        // out results
        System.out.println ("The distance between (" +x1+","+y1+") and ("+ x2 +","+y2+") is " + distance);
    }
}
    /
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Now it compiles but when I type in the first coordinate, it looks like this

```
 Enter the first set of coordinates: 
    (2,9)
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
        at C2p8.main(C2p8.java:17)

    Process completed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Keyboard` is not part of the standard library. Perhaps you meant `java.util.Scanner`, but that doesn't have `readInt()` method, it has `nextInt()`. There's a comment at the top of your code that tells you where it is, it looks like a custom class.

`Math` is `java.lang.Math`.

You're missing a `;` at the end of

```
double distance; // <missing that ;
```

And you have a dangling quote here

```
y1 = Keyboard.readInt();' // < what is that?
```

Get rid of it.

---

Had you used a proper IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/), [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/), or [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) you wouldn't have had any of these problems.

Comment: Ya, I didn't get to proof read any of it because I can't find the damn import in the standard library.

Comment: @Same Right, `Keyboard` doesn't exist in the JDK. It does apparently exist as your comment states `import csl.Keyboard from the L: drive jdk (this is for the school computers, not mine)`

Comment: @ Ok so I added Math import and changes all keyboard scanners to java.util scanners with nextInt(); and it still doesnt work

Comment: @Sam First, you don't need to impart `Math`, the `java.lang` package is automatically imported. Second, if you don't tell me how it doesn't work, I can't help you.

Comment: @Sam In your input, the character `(` is not an `int` so it fails because the input doesn't match what you expect. Enter the numbers separated by spaces. Something like `2 9 3 4`. Read up on how `Scanner` works.

Comment: So what, If I want to use () would I use String for the data type or char?

Comment: @Sam You would use String and parse it yourself to extract the numbers.

Comment: Well, thanks for dealing with my nooby bullshit for so long dude. I know I am a pain, but you're awesome.

Comment: @Sam LOL, you're welcome. Honestly, use JCreator for assignment submissions if your teacher is forcing you, but use a proper IDE for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The `Keyboard` class doesn't exist in the JDK. Probably it's a custom class made by your teacher of some sort. You would need either the .jar of that class or the actual code. Are you supposed to do your work in your computer? If that's the case the teacher probably gave you that file. The only class I think that you might be needing here instead of `Keyboard` is `Scanner` but that one has `nextInt()` not `readInt()` method. Also that one has to be instantiated, it is not static and it appears your `Keyboard` one is.

For the Math class, you're not supposed to import it. It is imported automatically always.

Comment: See, that's what I thought about the Math class, but I can't get this damn thing to work. I changed it all to nexint and it still gives me the same errors.

Comment: @Sam:  We can only address the main issue of the classes being incorrect/not imported in this question.  If you're still getting errors, **read through the compilation log** and try to pinpoint what's going wrong.

Comment: @Sam If you are going to use nexInt() now, you need to instantiate the Scanner. Just add a "Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);" line at the beginning of your main and change your "Keyboard" words for "keyboard". (variable names should not be uppercase, only classes)

Comment: @Did that now it compiles but when I go to type the coordiantes I want to calculate, after one of them it just does this:Enter the first set of coordinates: 
(2,9)
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
 at C2p8.main(C2p8.java:17)

Process completed.

Comment: @Sam We are not debuggers. Please, use a proper IDE and read about the Exceptions you get. Help us help you.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis JCreator is horrible isn't it. Well, like I said, it compiles but doesn't run like I want it to, it has a logical error I think, I just don't see how I got it wrong.

Comment: @Sam that exception means you typed something which wasn't an integer. Just in case you don't know, numbers with decimal points are not integers.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Math.* for the math...

For getting input from the keyboard, you need a scanner.

`Scanner scannerVariableNameWhichYouCouldCallKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`

so if you simply added the line `Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);`, all of your `Keyboard` lines would work.  You may have to `import java.util.Scanner;`.

And for reference, if you're working in Eclipse, you can have Eclipse automatically handle your imports by either hovering over the thing that needs an import and waiting for the pop up, or I think Ctrl+O.

Comment: apperently it's suppose to work without defining a scanner, idk my professor told us that.